# GLFW Undefined References

Tags: c++, mingw, netbeans-7, glfw

I'm trying to use GLFW on a project, but when I compile it, I get a lot of undefined reference errors, while many of them is on the library file (libglfw.a).
I tried both, compile the library and download it, but without success.
I'm using MinGW and MSYS running on Windows 7 32-bits on netbeans. The GLFW version is 2.7.3;

These are the errors:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Raphael/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prism'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/prism.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Raphael/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prism'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++.exe     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/prism build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/ByteBuffer.o -Lexternal -lglfw 
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Raphael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Prism/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `glMatrixMode@4'
C:\Users\Raphael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Prism/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity@0'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `Z6renderv':
C:\Users\Raphael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Prism/main.cpp:56: undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'
C:\Users\Raphael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Prism/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `glClear@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(window.o):window.c:(.text+0x8ae): undefined reference to `glClear@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0xe54): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0xe6c): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0xef6): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0xf4f): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0xf7f): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x174c): undefined reference to `wglMakeCurrent@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1935): undefined reference to `wglCreateContext@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x19fe): undefined reference to `wglMakeCurrent@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1a0e): undefined reference to `wglDeleteContext@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1ea6): undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1ebc): undefined reference to `glGetFloatv@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1ed8): undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1ee7): undefined reference to `glClear@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_window.o):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1f1a): undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(glext.o):glext.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(glext.o):glext.c:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(glext.o):glext.c:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(glext.o):glext.c:(.text+0x28b): undefined reference to `glGetString@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(glext.o):glext.c:(.text+0x2cf): undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libglfw.a(win32_glext.o):win32_glext.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Raphael/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prism'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Raphael/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prism'
'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/prism.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

CONSTRUIR FALHOU (valor da saída 2, tempo total:  1s)
```

Comment: Don't you have to link the OpenGL libs as well?  I don't see `libGL` or `libGLU`.  I know `glClear` is in either `libGL` or `libGLU`.  Posted as an answer because I'm 95% sure this is the problem...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't you have to link the OpenGL libs as well?  I don't see `libGL` or `libGLU`.  I know `glClear` is in either `libGL` or `libGLU`.

Comment: Well, since this was accepted as an answer, which one was it?

Comment: `glClear` is in `gl.h` (which is in libGL).

Answer (score 11):

In the linker, at Windows, MinGW: -lglew32 -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32

Put the libs and the includes files in MinGW and the dlls and exes at Windows systems folders.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was different. I was linking opengl32 in, but still getting the error. The problem turned out to be the library order: **glfw has to be linked in *before* opengl32**.

In my case this was in the "Link libraries" listbox in the Code::Blocks IDE, but it's going to be similar in NetBeans or on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The error I got is

```
undefined reference to `__imp_glfwInit'
```

fixed the problem after I change to glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64 (64 bit glfw)