# Undefined reference error in Qt Creator when using SDL and glew

Tags: c++, sdl, qt-creator, glew

I get error messages, when compiling my code. The output is next:

```
debug/display.o: In function `ZN7Display5clearEffff':
D:\Qt_Projects\TestProj\build-SomeOpenGLTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../SomeOpenGLTest/display.cpp:37: undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'
D:\Qt_Projects\TestProj\build-SomeOpenGLTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../SomeOpenGLTest/display.cpp:38: undefined reference to `glClear@4'
D:/Qt_Projects/TestProj/SomeOpenGLTest/lib/SDL2main.lib(./Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main]+0x5): undefined reference to `SDL_SetMainReady'
D:/Qt_Projects/TestProj/SomeOpenGLTest/lib/SDL2main.lib(./Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main]+0x12): undefined reference to `SDL_main'
D:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/Qt_Projects/TestProj/SomeOpenGLTest/lib/SDL2main.lib(./Release/SDL_windows_main.obj): bad reloc address 0x8 in section `.text[_WinMain@16]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All I'm trying to do is to connect *SDL2* and *glew* libraries to project and draw some window. My *.pro* file looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    display.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include

LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib \
            -lglew32 \
            -lglew32s \
            -lSDL2 \
            -lSDL2main \
            -lSDL2test

HEADERS += \
    display.h
```

I've got *include* folder with all *.hpp* files from libraries and also got *lib* folder with all *.lib* files from libraries.
I'm pretty sure, that problem is in linking libraries, but just in case give you my class code:
**display.h**

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H

#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Display
{
public:
    Display(int width = 360, int height = 360, const std::string &title = "Title");
    ~Display();

    void clear(float r, float g, float b, float a);
    void update();
    bool isClosed() const;

private:
    SDL_Window *mWindow;
    SDL_GLContext mGLContext;
    bool mIsClosed;
};

#endif // DISPLAY_H
```

**display.cpp**

```
#include "display.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>

Display::Display(int width, int height, const std::string &title)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    mWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height,
                               SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    // Context need in order to OpenGL take control of window from OS
    mGLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mWindow);

    GLenum status = glewInit();
    if (status != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "Glew failed to initialize!" << std::endl;
    }
}

Display::~Display()
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(mGLContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Display::clear(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void Display::update()
{
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mWindow);

    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
    {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            mIsClosed = true;
        }
    }
}

bool Display::isClosed() const
{
    return mIsClosed;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336263/glfw-undefined-references ?

Comment: @dtbeaver , yes, I did. But I don't know, where to find libGL or libGLU in order to set them in .pro file.

Comment: Did you try to simply add -lglew32 -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32 like recommended in that answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17216206/2807083

Comment: @dtbeaver, thanks for your replies, I have already found an answer,

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I needed to include this line of code to my *.pro* file:

```
LIBS += -L[my_compiler_directory]/lib -lopengl32
```

By means of this, I got rid of errors, related with undefined reference to `glFunctions'.
After that, thanks to [answer of **gefa**](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/110753/), I changed the order of *.lib* files like this:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib \
            -lglew32 \
            -lglew32s \
            -lSDL2main \
            -lSDL2 \
            -lSDL2test
```

so -lSDL2main is at the top of other SDL2 libs. After that, everything works properly.