# Why am I getting: "undefined reference to `glfwInit'"?

Tags: glfw, autotools, configure, automake, msys2

Whenever I try to compile my **OpenGL** sample project via **MSYS2**, **Autotools** and then `make` (*which uses statically compiled **GLEW** and **GLFW***) I am getting this kind of output:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include  -I./include/GL -I./include/GLFW -DGLEW_STATIC   -g -O2 -MT src/opengl_tut-main.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/opengl_tut-main.Tpo -c -o src/opengl_tut-main.o `test -f 'src/main.cpp' || echo './'`src/main.cpp
mv -f src/.deps/opengl_tut-main.Tpo src/.deps/opengl_tut-main.Po
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++  -g -O2 -L./lib -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32  -o opengl_tut.exe src/opengl_tut-main.o
src/opengl_tut-main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:41: undefined reference to `glfwGetFramebufferSize'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:45: undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `glewInit'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:58: undefined reference to `glViewport'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:62: undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:64: undefined reference to `glClearColor'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:65: undefined reference to `glClear'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:67: undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:60: undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:52: undefined reference to `glfwDestroyWindow'
C:\Users\Test\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
C:\Users\DoTestn\Desktop\OpenGL_2/src/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
src/opengl_tut-main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.glewExperimental[.refptr.glewExperimental]+0x0): undefined reference to `glewExperimental'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:361: opengl_tut.exe] Error 1
```

What I do not understand is that I am able to compile my code with manually typed command which looks like this:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -ggdb -Og -std=c++14 src/main.cpp -o bin/opengl_tut.exe -DGLEW_STATIC -I./include/GL -I./include/GLFW -L./lib -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

However, I would prefer to achieve the same result with *Autotools*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenGL GLFW: undefined reference to 'glfwInit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445942/opengl-glfw-undefined-reference-to-glfwinit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `src/opengl_tut-main.o` object probably depends on OpenGL libraries, so it must be listed before the OpenGL libraries in the final command that links everything together.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. When I modify that command to: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -g -O2 src/opengl_tut-main.o -L./lib -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -o opengl_tut.exe` - it goes well.  But what should I do to make *Autoconf* / *Automake* do the same?

Comment: Apparently, changing `_LDFLAGS` to `_LDADD` (*in **Makefile.am***) is enough and solves my problem.

Comment: Yes, @Don, libraries should be listed in `*LDADD`, not `*LDFLAGS`.  This is the whole point of the `LDADD` variables, in fact.  `-L` options can be listed in either place, but all other linker options (as opposed to objects and libraries to link) should be included in `LDFLAGS`.