# GLFW header is recognized, but the methods included in it aren't

Tags: c, gcc, glfw

Ok so I have a bit of a weird issue. I downloaded GLFW through the terminal on my Debian WSL. VSCode (and the autocomplete) acknowledged the header files AND the methods exist, even giving the method information on hover. However, GCC does know the header file exists (and does not throw an error when referenced), yet throws errors when I reference the methods included in the header.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk0mH.png)

Errors thrown:

```
gcc -o ge all-src/new-src/GameObject.o all-src/new-src/main.o all-src/new-src/V2.o all- 
src/new-src/V3.o -Wall  
all-src/new-src/main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
main.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
main.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
main.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
main.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
main.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
main.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: That is a linker error, which means that you aren't linking against the (compiled) library

Comment: how would one link a library through a makefile to gcc?

Comment: Your question looks like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925780/i-get-linker-errors-when-trying-to-compile-my-opengl-project-using-gcc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get linker errors when trying to compile my opengl project using gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925780/i-get-linker-errors-when-trying-to-compile-my-opengl-project-using-gcc)